# Apache-Commons Sanselan AIOOBE when decompressing PackBits TIFF

Tags: java, apache-commons, indexoutofboundsexception

Out-of-the-box ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when attempting to use Apache-Commons Sanselan to load a TIFF that was compressed with PackBits compression.

Code:

```
import org.apache.sanselan.*;

public class TIFFHandler {
    public static Image loadTIFF(String fileName) throws ImageReadException, IOException {
        File imageFile = new File(fileName);
        BufferedImage bi = Sanselan.getBufferedImage(imageFile);
        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ImageReadException {
        String TIFFFILE = "test_image.tif";
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) loadTIFF(TIFFFILE);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(bi);
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(ii);
        panel.add(lbl);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 426
at org.apache.sanselan.common.PackBits.decompress(PackBits.java:55)
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.datareaders.DataReader.decompress(DataReader.java:127)
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.datareaders.DataReaderStrips.readImageData(DataReaderStrips.java:96)
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffImageParser.getBufferedImage(TiffImageParser.java:505)
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffDirectory.getTiffImage(TiffDirectory.java:163)
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffImageParser.getBufferedImage(TiffImageParser.java:441)
at org.apache.sanselan.Sanselan.getBufferedImage(Sanselan.java:1264)
at org.apache.sanselan.Sanselan.getBufferedImage(Sanselan.java:1255)
at TIFFHandler.loadTIFF(FieldSheetHandler.java:42)
at TIFFHandler.main(FieldSheetHandler.java:90)
```

I've attempted an analysis of the problem, but I'm pretty lost...any directions would be really helpful.  TIFF images are a pain in the a**.

Comment: Did you try with the code from the trunk? Commons Sanselan (to be renamed Commons Imaging) has changed a lot lately as it progress towards a 1.0 release.

Comment: I'm using the most recent .JAR file (sanselan-0.97.incubator.jar) -- is this the trunk code?  There doesn't seem to be a trunk/branch differentiation...

Comment: No it's 3 years old. You can fetch the nightly build jars from the Apache snapshot repository: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Wonderful!  This mostly fixes my problems (I'll accept an answer if you'll post one).  Also, is there an updated Javadoc for Commons-imaging?  I need a way to load a specific sub-image of a TIFF without loading all of the sub-images (due to memory constraints)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the updated version of Commons Imaging from the Apache snapshot repository. The Javadoc is not online yet, you'll have to build it by [checking out the code from SVN](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/source-repository.html) and running `mvn javadoc:javadoc`.

If you find more issues or want to suggest an improvement you can file them in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMAGING). Also the developers will be happy to help you if you have questions regarding the usage of the API. They await you on the [mailing list](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/mail-lists.html).

Comment: Thanks for this; it's exactly what I needed!  I was able to build a new method to get only the BufferedImage I want, instead of the first or all.